# Change location of Wordpress signup redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

By default, Wordpress redirects to `https://exampe.com/wp-login.php?checkemail=registered` on successful signup.

However, I would like to redirect to `https://example.com/thanks-for-joining`. This will be a landing page with various things a new user can do.

I have changed the redirect location from `checkemail=registered` to the desired URL, but this has not worked.

I think I need to change something in this section of code too, also from wp-login.php. This is where I'm stuck:

```
elseif  ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && 'registered' == $_GET['checkemail'] )
            $errors->add('registered', __('Registration complete. Please check your email.'), 'message');
```

Are you able to advise which changes to make to achieve the desired redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your active theme's function.php

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'my_redirect' );
   function my_redirect( $registration_redirect ) {
   return "http://localhost/testing2/test";
}
```

Change the URL where you want it to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your themes `function.php` file

```
function redirect_registration() {
    return home_url( 'https://example.com/thanks-for-joining' );
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'redirect_registration' );
```

I believe there are plugins that can accomplish this. You can use this method also.